# Flutter add Items to ListView

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a ListView and i would like to add a new Text Widget every Time i pressed a Button. The User should be able to insert the String inside the Text Widget when the Button is pressed. Is there any way to do this?

```
ListView(children: [
         //New Widget here evertime the Button is pressed
        ]),
ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()
              {
                //Add New Item when this is pressed
              }
              , child: Text("Add Item"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `ListView` you should use a `ListView.builder`, and a `List<Widget>` variable `_strings` where all the new strings stored. An example code below:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> _strings = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _strings.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => _strings[index],
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _strings.add(
                      Text('new text added'),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Text('Add String'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked out fine. Is it possible to delete an Item whenever i click on the specific item or can i just delete like the first or last element of the List?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Yes you can remove an item in a similar way, with the `remove` method `_strings.remove[0]` inside a `setState`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ListViewBuilder` instead with a `StatefulWidget` and I'd suggest using a `FloatingActionButton` in the Scaffold Widget.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {

 const MyApp();

_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  List<String> list = [];  

  _onPressed(String val) {
    setState((){
       list.add(val);     
    });

_listViewBuilder() {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text(list[index]);
      });
}
  
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _listViewBuilder(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          _onPressed("Text To Add");
        },
        tooltip: 'add',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
}
}
```